# TMC5160 stepper driver - one phase seems to be offset and clipped

Tags: control, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I am using the [TMC5160 stepper driver](https://learn.watterott.com/de/silentstepstick/pinconfig/tmc5160/) with a stepper motor. I am configuring it in SPI mode from an STM32F4. I used the sample commands from the [datasheet](https://www.trinamic.com/products/integrated-circuits/details/tmc5160/) on page 116 (section 23 *getting started*) with lower velocity and acceleration values - but it also happens with the normal values.

The power supply has a current limit of 2 A which I am nowhere near. I drive the board with 12 V.
It seemed to work okay, but then after some playing around with different velocities, one phase seems to be offset and clipped (see photo) whereas the other one is still fine. I am not able to get it back in a working configuration (pulling power and turning it back on did not work); it seems to be stuck in this mode.

I actually have two motors and two drivers and it happens with both of them. The cable should be fine, otherwise I would not be able to measure it with the current-probe of the oscilloscope, right? Does anyone have an idea what this shape could mean?

[image: oscilloscope screen showing currents in both phases]